# When I log into my networks homepage it is not working

Tags: php, html, mysqli, xampp

When I log into my networks homepage it is not working. I have connected to the database and can create new users however when I log in I am getting the else statement that shows my session is not working. (It was redirecting back to log in but for learning purposes I set it to echo).

Below is my log in code and homepage code (basic structure). I know it is not secure yet I am still getting to the security part I just need to figure out why this error is happening.

```
<?php require ("insert.php"); ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST[ 'Login' ]))
    {
    session_start();
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['email']);
    $pswrd= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['pswrd']);

    $result = $con->query(" select * from users where email='$email' AND pswrd='$pswrd' ");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);



    $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['User_ID'];
    header ('Location: home.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>AMSadler login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description of webpage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords go here">
    <meta name="author" content="Anthony">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="index" href="index.php">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="AMSadler.com"/></a>
            </div>

            <div id="signup">
                <button type="button"><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <form method="post" action="home.php">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <input id="Login" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div id="copyright">
                <p>&copy Copyright 2015</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

</body>
</html>


<?php require ("insert.php"); 
session_start(); 
if (isset($_SESSION ["UserID"] ) ) {
}
else {
    echo "not fixed";
    // header ('Location: login.php');
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>AMSadler</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description of webpage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords go here">
    <meta name="author" content="Anthony">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">

            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="AMSadler.com"/></a>
            </div>

            <div id="headertop">
                <div id="pagetitle">
                    <a href="home.php">HOME</a>
                </div>

                <div id="pagetitle2">
                    <a href="profile.php">PROFILE</a>
                </div>
                <div id="pagetitle3">
                    <h4>Welcome:<?php echo $_SESSION["UserID"];?>to your page</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class="leftsidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.php">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jhbjhbjhb</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jhbbjhb</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jhbbjhbj</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jhbhjbjhb</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">bjhbjhb</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">rege</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">rgerger</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">dfbrtbr</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sdvdfgbd</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="main">
                    <div id="maintop">
                        <div id="textboxwrap">
                            <textarea name="text" id="styled"rows="5" cols="80" placeholder="Write something here.">
                            </textarea> 
                        </div>

                        <div id="postbutton">
                            <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="mainbottom1">
                        <div ="mainbottomwrap">
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>
                            Your posts will go here.<br>Your posts will go here.<br>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="rightsidebar">
                    <div id="profilecontainer">
                        <img src="img/profile.png" alt="Upload a profile pic" title="profile pic" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="box">
                        <a href="#">fgtdhrth</a><br>
                        <a href="#">dfbrt</a><br>
                        <a href="#">gverb</a><br>
                        <a href="#">dsvfe</a><br>
                        <a href="#">egerg</a><br>
                        <a href="#">wefgeger</a><br>
                        <a href="#">rfthrtth</a><br>
                        <a href="#">gergreg</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server-side code for logging in is never actually invoked.  That code is expecting the form to POST back to that same page (the login page).  But instead, it posts to the next page (the home page):

```
<form method="post" action="home.php">
```

The result is that you never set the session variable on the login page, so there's no value to be read on the home page.

POST the form to the page which expects to handle the form:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
```

Also please note that **storing user passwords in *plain text*** is a famously **bad** idea.  You're going to want to [obscure those passwords with a 1-way hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).  Anything else is grossly negligent to your users.

Comment: Ok thank you i have fixed that post however I am still getting the else echo on my home page and the user id echo statement is being displayed however the users id is not being displayed. I still have to learn about obscuring passwords that is my next tutorial  but thank you for the advice on that.

Comment: @AnthonySadler: At this point I suspect a little more debugging is required, which is a skill you're going to want to practice.  It's possible, for example, that your database interaction isn't working at all and as a result nothing is being stored in the session variable.  You might want to check error reporting, check error logs, look into catching and examining errors in the database technology you're using.